# make a confusion matrix for a classifier with 2 classes

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, confusion-matrix

I have a file with some sentences (A Persian sentence, a tab, a Persian word (tag), a tab, an English word (tag)). The English words show the class of each sentence. There are 2 classes in this file, "passion" and "salty". I classified the sentences with naive bayes algorithm and now I have to calculate precision and recall. For that I have to make a confusion matrix but I don't know how. I wrote a small code and assumed that "passion" is the positive group and "salty" is the negative group. The code returned the output for this case. But if I assume "salty" as positive and "passion" as negative, the numbers are totally different from the first case, and consequently when I want to calculate precision and recall, I don't have the correct answer. Should I calculate tp, tn, fp and fn separately for the 2 classes (once for passion and once for salty) and then calculate the average and then calculate precision and recall according to this average?

(hint1: argmax is the output of the NB algorithm and it is the tag that the code recognized it for the test sentences.
hint2: I have some other files with more than 2 classes, too)

```
#t = line.strip().split("\t")
if t[2] == "passion" and argmax == "passion":
    tp += 1
elif t[2] == "passion" and argmax != "passion":
    fn += 1
elif t[2] == "salty" and argmax != "salty":
    fp += 1
elif t[2] == "salty" and argmax == "salty":
    tn += 1
print ("tp", tp, "tn", tn, "fp", fp, "fn", fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org), which already provides confusion matrix and classification reports. A sample:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
# suppose your predictions are stored in a variable called preds
# and the true values are stored in a variable called y
print(confusion_matrix(y, preds))
print(classification_report(y, preds))
```

(btw, scikit-learn is intended to be used with python 2.7, but it is probably safe to use these functions, since you already have the model built).

Also, since I see you are in the NLP domain, you could use the facilities that the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) library provides. I'm not an expert, but I suppose [this](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.confusionmatrix) should be useful.